# Change SSL Protocol Torndao 2.3/Python 2.6

Tags: python, ssl, tornado, python-2.6

I'm running an older version of python (2.6) and tornado (2.3). In my program I have an instance of HTTPClient running fetch() requesting an https url on facebook. However, it's trying to make the request over SSLv3. Since Facebook disabled SSLv3 when POODLE happened, the request is throwing a handshake failure.

I can't figure out where to change the protocol, if I even can. Is there any way I can change it to use TLS with these older versions? This is a legacy application that I was just given to fix asap, so I'm not sure of the implication of updating any of the libraries.

Heres the error I'm receiving:
`SSL Error on 16: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up upgrading tornado to version 3.2 since there was a change made to `simple_httpclient` that changed it's protocol from sslv3 to tlsv1, as stated here http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/v3.2.0.html#tornado-simple-httpclient